# como puedo sumar los precios de los productos seleccionados en el carrito de la compra?

Tags: reactjs

estoy desarrollando un ecommerce en reactjs, y estoy tratando de sumar los precios de los productos que hay en el carrito de la compra en un total, con el método reduce de JS, pero en vez de sumar los precios me los concatena, alguna idea de como poder hacerlo?............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
function CartList() {
  const cartItems = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();



  function handleRemoveFromCart(item) {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(item));
  }

  

  const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
    ...theme.typography.body2,
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  }));

  
    return (
      <>
      <NavBar />
       <Header />
       <div className="container-xl">
       <div className="cart-titel"><h1>Cart</h1></div>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={6} md={8}>
            <Item>
            <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents shop_table--show-thumb-mobile" cellspacing="0">
                     <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th className="product-name" colspan="2">PRODUCT
                        
                         </th>
                        
                       <th className="product-quantity" colspan="2">QUANTITY
                       
                        </th>
                       
                        <th className="product-subtotal" colspan="2">SUBTOTAL</th>
                        
                      </tr>
                      
                      
                    </thead>                  
                  </table>
                  </Item>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={6} md={8}>
                    <Item>
                  {cartItems && cartItems.length > 0 ? (
                    cartItems.map((item) => (
                  <div className="cont-product-cart">
                   <div className="line"></div>
                   <tbody>
                     <tr>
                     <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites" type="button" onClick={() => handleRemoveFromCart(item)}>
                     <DeleteForeverOutlinedIcon/>
                      </IconButton>
                   
                       <td className="product-thumbnail">
                         <img src={item.image} />
                       </td>
                       <td className="product-name">
                         <p>{item.name}</p>
                         <p>{item.price}€</p>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                       <div className="quantity">
                           <input type="number"/>
                         </div>
                       </td>
                     </tr>
                   </tbody>
                  </div>
                   ))
                  
                   ) : (
                     <h4 className="text-danger">The cart is empty</h4>
                   )}
            </Item>
          </Grid>
         
          <Grid item xs={6} md={4}>
            <Item>
            <div className="total-title">TOTAL</div>
            <div>{(
               cartItems?.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0)
              
             
            )}</div>
            </Item>
          </Grid>

          </Grid>
      </Box>
      
    </div>
  </>
    )
}
export default CartList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David.
Eso es porque estás intentando "**sumar**" cadenas, y por ello las concatena, para sumarlas antes tienes que convertirlas a integer...
Algo como esto, pero adecuado a tu código, claro:

```
<script>
    var price = '5'
    var amount = '7'
    
    alert(parseInt(price) + parseInt(amount))
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Francisco, no había caído en eso, al poner parseInt ya me funciona.